# Is $\int_0^2 f(x) dx$ defined for $f(x)=x,x \ne 1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f(x)=x,x \ne 1$.

Is $$\int_0^2 f(x) dx$$ defined?

I'm currently a high school student, and we learn that the integral is the area under the graph. But in calculus textbooks and websites, I see some stuff about "continuity" and things being "integrable". So I was wondering if this simple case is considered "integrable" (because $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)$ is defined) or not (because it has a value "missing" altogether, rather than being discontinuous but still integrable like a step function).

Thanks!

Comment: $f(x)$ does not make any appearance in the integral. Did you mean $\int_{0}^{2} f(x) dx$?

Comment: If the integral is "*the area under the curve*", what is your definition of *area* of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Is such area affected by the removal of a point or a segment?

Comment: It's probably not intended by the OP, but the way I read it, I would wholeheartedly agree with Aryabhata. Otherwise, I think the provided answer of MAthematicsStudent is a good one

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Technically speaking, no, it isn't, since the function needs to be defined on the entire interval $[0,2]$ for the integral over $[0,2]$ to be well-defined. That said, you can define $f(1)$ however you want so that you have a function defined on $[0,2]$; if you do this, the integral is defined and its value is $2$.

Comment: A single point has zero Lesbegue measure, and therefore has no impact on the integral.

Comment: First, I'm assuming Riemann integration, which is only defined on closed intervals. Second, the integral in question is $\int_{0}^{2} f$, not $\int_{[0,2] \setminus \{1\}} f$. Assuming $f$ is defined on $[0,2] \setminus \{1\}$, then  $\int_{0}^{2} f$, is _undefined_ (even as a Lebesgue integral) even though $\int_{[0,2] \setminus \{1\}} f$ is defined, because you cannot integrate over $[0,2]$ if the function is not defined on $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 10):

To integrate a function over a region, say $[a,b]$, $f(x)$ must be well-defined on that region. Here $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=1$. So you can not integrate. Given the question you ask, this is enough to answer your question. But if you want to know more, note that you can assign any real value at $x=1$ to make the function well-defined, and then  you can do the following:

$f(x)=x$, $x\neq 1$. Then $f(x)$ may not be continuous at $x=1$.

Then take $f(1)=a$, here $a$ may not be $1$.

But note this: For any $\epsilon>0$,

$$\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}f(x)dx+\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}f(x)dx+\int_{1+\epsilon}^{2}f(x)dx$$

So what is going on here?

**(1)** You know that $\int_{c}^{c}g(x)=0$, for any function $g(x)$, since integration over a single point is $0$, and it does not depends on continuity.

Now $$\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}f(x)dx=\Big[\dfrac{x^2}{2}\Big]_{0}^{1-\epsilon}=\dfrac{(1-\epsilon)^2}{2}\space\text{and}\space\int_{1+\epsilon}^{2}f(x)dx=\Big[\dfrac{x^2}{2}\Big]_{1+\epsilon}^{2}=\dfrac{4-(1+\epsilon)^2}{2}$$

But using (1), $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}f(x)dx=\int_{1}^{1}adx=0$$

Hence the answer is $$\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\Big(\dfrac{(1-\epsilon)^2}{2}+\dfrac{4-(1+\epsilon)^2}{2}\Big)=2$$

Comment: This one seems unnecessarily complicated with all those $\epsilon$ and limit stuff. This is not an improper integral.

Comment: The right approach is understand that once $f$ is defined at $1$ in any manner the integral exists (because the function is bounded and has at most a finite number of discontinuities). The evaluation is easy because the discontinuity is of a simple kind and the integral can be split over multiple intervals via the points of discontinuity. And the discontinuity can now be removed in each interval and the integral can be evaluated using anti-derivative.

Comment: The reason your approach works is because if the integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ exists then integral $\int_{a}^{x} f(t) \, dt$ is continuous.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh you are right, I guess $\int_{a}^{a}g(x)=0$ and and your last comment are the key result here...

Comment: Why do we need the integral $\int_a^a g(x) \, dx$. For the particular example here we are even luckier because the discontinuity is removable directly without split of interval and hence integral is equal to $\int_0^2 x\, dx=2$.

Comment: But @ParamanandSingh he said he is a high school student... can I assume he knows stuff like this?

Comment: He knows limits and discontinuity. These are simpler ones. If one does not know limits/continuity/discontinuity then one is not supposed to learn integral/derivative. Unfortunately some countries do teach math in this erroneous and dangerous fashion and God help them.

Comment: In fact OP clearly mentions that limit of $f$ at $1$ exists so he may well be told to define the function to make it continuous at $1$ and proceed.

Comment: The gist of this answer is correct, but the 'middle piece' (the $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ segment) is handled very sloppily in a subject (integration) where sloppiness can be dangerous. You haven't shown that the limit exists _or_ that it equals the specified value (i.e., zero) without quite a bit of additional reasoning. Instead, it would be better to appeal to the 'core' definition of the Riemann integral and take advantage of the convenient nature of the integrand here to provide explicit bounds on the value via partitions.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki as I told previously, OP said he is a high school student. I can use Riemann( or Lebesgue) integral and write integration over zero measure set is zero etc, but I am not sure OP knows those thing...

Answer (score 5):

To integrate a function over an interval $A=[a,b]$, the function must be defined on all $A$.

If $f$ is not defined on a finite number of points $x_1, \dots, x_n \in A$, you can still try to give the integral a well-defined value using the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), which simply means we integrate around all the discontinuities:

If $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n$, we define

$$I=P.V.\int_a^b f(x)\,dx := \\
\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \left(\int_a^{x_1-\epsilon}f(x)\,dx+\int_{x_1+\epsilon}^{x_2-\epsilon}f(x)\,dx+\cdots+\int_{x_n+\epsilon}^{b}f(x)\,dx\right)$$

In this case, we have

$$P.V. \int_0^2 f(x)\,dx = \\
\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon} x\,dx+\int_{1+\epsilon}^{2} x\,dx\right) =\\
 \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\frac{(1-\epsilon)^2}{2}+\frac{2^2}{2}-\frac{(1+\epsilon)^2}{2}\right) = 2$$

---

Incidentally, you can alternatively define $f(1)=c$ to be *any value* so that the integral is then well-defined. Then the integral would equal

$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 x\,dx + \int_1^1 c\,dx + \int_1^2 x\,dx = 2$$

which is the same value as before. You can further generalize this principle, and say that if

$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x       & \quad \text{if } x \neq x_i \text{ for all }i=1\dots n\\
    c_i  & \quad \text{if } x = x_i\text{ for some }i=1\dots n\\
  \end{cases}$$

the value of the integral remains unchanged:

$$\int_0^2 f(x)\,dx=2$$

Comment: The Wikipedia article which you have linked clearly mentions the conditions under which Cauchy principle value is used and this particular integral is not covered under those cases. It is unnecessarily complicated and similar to the one given in another answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh PV is often used for integrating functions with real-valued poles like $1/x$. Does $\int_{-1}^1\frac 1xdx$ fall under one of the categories? At any rate, I think that PV is the most meaningful way to integrate nearly any function with singularities, and is thus a meaningful generalization. PV can be used to evaluate the case presented here, but also $\frac 1x$ which cannot be evaluated by simply assigning a value to $f(0)$.

Comment: It is used to deal with  singularities which lead to values like $\pm\infty$ for the integral and not for integrand. In any case this is not used for other discontinuities like jump or removable or finite oscillation because it is unnecessary.

Comment: The current case does not require anything apart from definition of $f$ at $1$ and after that the definition of integral takes care of everything.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh So what? PV is more general and meaningful. Just because it appears to be more complex doesn't mean it should be dismissed ab initio. It is an important method.

Comment: I think you are not getting the point. A generalization is supposed to satisfy some need. It is not done just for the heck of it. The theories of improper Riemann integrals, Cauchy principal value, Lebesgue integral were developed to handle cases which could not be handled by Riemann integral.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh What makes this "for the heck of it?" The case presented here *cannot* be handled by the Riemann integral. Just because it takes two extra lines doesn't mean it is overkill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64272/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-argon).

Comment: @Argon thanks for your answer. could you recommend any other resource to read about Cauchy pv apart from wikipedia?

Answer (score 0):

The Riemann integral over [0,2] is not define at all since f is not defined at 1, and hence not defined on the interval as a whole. This is not just a technicality. The integral is no more defined on [1,1] than the value of the function is at x=1. It is not a technicality - but it is a removable problem.

If a well behaved f is extended to [0,2] by stating any finite real value at 1, then the integral is defined and the value is independent of the choice of finite value at 1. But, if distributions are accepted to extend f, then an impulse at x=1 would produce a different value for the integral depending on the height chosen for the impulse.

If the integration is taken with respect to a measure, then the choice of measure on the singleton interval [1,1] will affect the integral as well.

The Cauchy principle value approach is to take limits near a singularity. The Cauchy principle value specifies the manner of taking that limit. But, the exact way in which that limit is taken can change the value obtained for the integral, or make it undefined. So, one can only say that the Cauchy principle value integral is such and such. In this case if f was continuous to begin with the value is independent of the limit. But if it f is not continuous then the integral might vary.

Perhaps counter-intuitively, what makes a function more seriously non integrable is strong enough failure to be continuous. Although an occasional jump discontinuity is no problem. If there is an infinite number of discontinuities in a finite region, then the failure of the existence of a representative value for the function on any finite interval leads to failure of the attempt to integrate.

That is - all the above was a discussion of removable problems in integration, but functions that take on one value at rationals and others at irrationals can be much more seriously non integrable due to their inherent nature - not just their context.

Lebesgue integral, Henstock, Kurzweil, etc - there are many ideas for what an integral is, just like there are many ideas for the sum of an infinite series (eg the Cesaro sum). Hardy wrote a book on the manipulation of classically non convergent series, for example. See also - Pfeffer, the Riemann approach to integration. It discusses a number of the issues of integrability from a fairly concrete perspective.

Answer (score -1):

A single bad point in the interval that is integrated has zero Lesbegue measure, so it has zero impact on the integral.   However, study of Lesbegue theory of measure and integration is normally done in a graduate level class on analysis of functions of real variables and you may not have been there yet.

If you limit yourself to the Riemann method of integration, you cannot define the upper and lower sums for that bad point, so the integral cannot be defined.